# listing directory content not working with variable

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, scripting

I am trying to print content at path with variable in terminal but unfortunately its not working for me.

INPUT

```
$ LX_PATH="/Users/pc/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2018-10-10/App\ 10-10-18\,\ 11.16\ AM.xcarchive"
$ ls $LX_PATH
```

OUTPUT

```
ls: /Users/pc/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2018-10-10/App\: No such file or directory
ls: 10-10-18\,\: No such file or directory
ls: 11.16\: No such file or directory
ls: AM.xcarchive: No such file or directory
```

But when i try without variable like below its working!!

```
ls /Users/pc/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2018-10-10/App\ 10-10-18\,\ 11.16\ AM.xcarchive
```

OUTPUT

```
BCSymbolMaps    Info.plist  Products    SwiftSupport    dSYMs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are "over-escaping" the contents of your LX_PATH. When you define LX_PATH, you are using double quotes, which means that spaces don't need to be escaped (but dollar signs need). You will also need to quote the variable in `ls`, otherwise the shell will try to parse it and complain at spaces. Try with:

```
$ LX_PATH="/Users/pc/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2018-10-10/App 10-10-18, 11.16 AM.xcarchive"
$ ls "$LX_PATH"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... @Poshi